# Program for printing

Tags: php, c++

I want to write a program for printing stuff on a paper, roughly what commands or classes do i need to use in c++ or php to get me started ?

Comment: Don't think this is an easy task, you are looking to code a driver I guess, but your goal is not even clear to you. Trust me that it won't be as simple as writing a PHP script, for instance

Answer (score 1):

In C++, printing is handled by the operating system and thus platform specific.  In general here are the following choices:

1. Print to console, have OS redirect
   console output to printer.
2. Print to file, then use OS to print
   to the file.
3. Print to printer using printer name
   as filename
4. Use OS API to print.

There are many ways in C++ to send data outside of the program.  The standard methods are to use streams (using `<<` operator) and C-style streams (using `FILE *` and `fprintf`).

Please provide platform information so more detailed assistance may be given.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which platform. For Linux I would look at: http://www.cups.org/

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention PHP, the easiest way out in this case would be to simply output HTML and CSS, using a browser to print it.

Besides that, I'm not aware of any ways of accomplishing this with just PHP.

Comment: I don't want to use a program already designed, i want to write my own

Answer (score 0):

To print on the paper using php generally developers prefer JavaScript for the same, provided you are running your page on browser. 
The following code can used to do so

`<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;">Print Me</a>`

Same kind of topic is discussed in following thread

[Click this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470995/how-to-print-to-a-paper-in-php)