# How to send the content of an external file to printer?

Tags: php, file, printing

I want to print (printer, not screen) the content of a file via a PHP script.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

php cannot easily access hardware.  This is generally not considered "possible."

See:

- [SO "how to "print" to paper"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470995/how-to-print-to-a-paper-in-php)
- [How to print directly to printer](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/15881)

However, as the first link shows, this is usually done with Javascript.  You can output Javascript in a way similar to the methods shown on the first link to force the browser to show the print dialog box.

### Original

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to print files into a variable or to the output stream.

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents("myfilename.txt");
print $filecontents;
```

You can also [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) files into your PHP interpretation.

Comment: I want to give a print command to a printer...!
Read the content and print a file remotely via PHP script...!
CAn u pls help me with that..???

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty way to print on the client's computer is something like:

```
print file_get_contents("file.ext");
print "<script>window.print()</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly not what your question intended, but on any Linux server with a connected printer you could use following:

```
exec("lp file.pdf");   // send file to printer spooler
```

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/449709/php-print-pdf-directly-to-a-printer) will help you. It offers a java library to send print jobs via cmd over php scripts.

Answer (score -3):

```
// to open a local file use this
$file_handler = fopen("data.txt", "r"); 


// read the contents 
$contents = fread($file_handler, filesize($file)); 

// close the file 
fclose($file_handler); 

// print the contents on your page 
echo $contents;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer what OP wants, to print the file on the physical printer.