# How to send Escape Code to encode a Magnetic Stripe ID card with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, printing, tcpdf, magnetic-cards

I need to **encode** magnetic stripe on ID cards, It's very simple we just need to send a string like this : ~1%123456? to the printer with a software like notepad or word... The printer will encode the track one, and write %123456? on the magstripe.

But I need to do it with TCPDF, I try all functions like MultiCell, Text, Write or writeHTMLCell but the result is it just **print** "~1%123456?" on the card. The printer does not **encode** the card.

I read somewhere that PDF create an image and send it to the printer, so the printer don't see the text to encode, just the image to print.

Any suggestions to overcome this? Can we add data header to be interpreted by the printer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send the content of an external file to printer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627035/how-to-send-the-content-of-an-external-file-to-printer)

Comment: no, I can print, that's not the problem, I need to print text from a PDF build with TCPDF that is not rasterized.

Comment: Hmm, after more test, the text is NOT rastered in PDF, so it should be good. The problem seem to be on the PDF print engine. PDF are flattened before sent to the printer. this is were my encoding string is converted to vector or something.